# MySQL5.6対応で「doesn't have a default value」となるエラーの差分migrationの動的生成方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

MySQL5.6から NOT NULL制約 を付けているのに、DEFAULT値が設定されていない場合は、
INSERT等が出来なくなってしまっています。

オプションで変更することも可能なのですが……。
既に出来上がっているデータベースの構造から全テーブル、全カラムを確認して、
問題解決するための migration(差分) を用意するには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

全てのテーブル名は、ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tablesで取得できます。
このテーブル名１つ１つを、classifyして、constantizeすればクラス処理できます。

クラス毎に、.columnsで全カラムを取得して、処理していきます。

1. column.name が class.primary_key だったら 次カラムへスキップ。
   　　※ おそらく id であり PRIMARY_KEY がついているはずです。
2. column.null が true だったら次カラムへスキップ
3. column.default が nil でなければ次カラムへスキップ
4. column.cast_type.typeを判定して、デフォルト値を決定する。
5. change_column_default文を組み立てて出力する。

そういう需要で作ったサンプルコードも提示しておきます。

```
default_values = {
    integer: 0, text: nil, string: '', boolean: false,
    datetime: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    decimal: 0, float: 0.0
}
tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
klasses = tables.map(&:classify).map do |class_name|
  begin
    class_name.constantize
  rescue NameError
  end
end
klasses.uniq!.compact!
klasses.each do |klass|
  pkey = klass.primary_key
  klass.columns.each do |column|
    type, null, default = column.cast_type.type, column.null, column.default
    next if column.name == pkey
    next if null == true or not default.nil?
    raise "ERROR: #{klass.name}.#{column.name} with #{type} not support yet." unless default_values.has_key?(type.to_sym)
    next if (value = default_values[type]).nil?
    puts "change_column_default :#{klass.table_name}, :#{column.name}, #{value.inspect}"
  end
end
```